# How do I modify the user interface language in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

How do I modify the user interface language in SQL Server Management Studio?

For instance, if I installed in English, but wish to view in Japanese (to name but one possible example).

I am running this environment in a non-[English-as-a-first-language] environment, and would prefer all my windows to read in my natural language. (my particular natural language isn't really important is it?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might help:

[Install SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Multilingual User Interface (MUI) system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/petersad/install-sql-server-2008-r2-on-a-multilingual-user-interface-mui-system) on MSDN by [Peter Saddow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/Peter%20Saddow%20-%20Microsoft)

From that link:

> In summary:

- English SQL Server is supported on all localized versions of operating systems
- Localized versions of SQL Server are supported on the same localized operating system or English system with MUI enabled for the same language.

You can also reinstall it using a different language version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 14):

To change the language in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014:

```
> Tools > Options... > Environment > International Settings > Language
```

[image: see the screenshot]

Comment: It's good way to change it, but there is nothing about how to add a language to list.

Comment: You need to change Windows regional standards and language to **English**. Windows prompt you for restart. -> open SSMS again and you should be good to go

Comment: I installed another lang pack but i still unable to choose english. I want to keep my system language as it is (non-eng) with dev tools using english (MSVS/SSMS and so on). Is it possible? Becuase language pack is on the system but list is still single-element one.

Comment: My configuration:
1) windows 7 - german
2) SSMS - (installed by someone else) - german
3) regional settings - english
--
as you see from screenshoot I do have both options

Comment: Doesn't work with SSMS 17.6 and Windows 10 German.

Comment: I have Win10 with keyboard layout set to de-DE and display language en-US. This setting is set to "Same as Microsoft Windows" which I would expect to be en-US but SSMS is in German. I can only select "Deutsch" and "Wie Microsoft Windows".
So which regional settings are you talking about @Vojta? Win10 is unfortunately a mess concerning languages. I have so many mixed menus with English and German. I even set the `Region & language` to United States just to test this. Also didn‘t work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your regional settings within Windows. Once you set your region and language preference your UI should be updated.